# Unable to cast String to DateTime

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, datetime, ajaxcontroltoolkit, textchanged

I've following TextBox with ajax calender extender and on TextChanged event I am calling **"txtFromDate_TextChanged"** function.

**asp code:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            ontextchanged="txtFromDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
  asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtFromDate_CalendarExtender" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                            TargetControlID="txtFromDate">
                        </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

**c# code:**

```
protected void txtFromDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (txtFromDate.Text != "")
  {
    DateTime fromdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text);
    Query = Query + "And   CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, ord_del_date))) >= '" + fromdate.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd") + "'";

  }
}
```

This code is working all fine when i debug through visual studio and even when I host the site on my local IIS server.
The problem is that when I host the site on my **online hosting server** and when I pick a date from calender and calls a textchanged event it gives following error:

**Error:**

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

I know it is giving error because of line:

```
DateTime fromdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text);
```

But I am not finding anything wrong in this code.
This code is working perfectly fine from visual studio or when hosted on IIS but I am totally confused why it isn't working when hosted on hosting server. I am totally confused. Please help me out.

Comment: Well what's the value of `txtFromDate.Text`? And why are you building up SQL dynamically rather than using parameterized SQL? My guess is that the problem is the server using the system-local culture, and that you should use `DateTime.ParseExact` specifying the invariant culture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime fromdate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtToDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

Query = Query + "And   CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, ord_del_date))) >= '" + fromdate.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd") + "'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing date format in aspx to

```
dd-MMM-yyyy (if you want month)
```

or

```
dd-MM-yyyy (if you want only month)
```

Answer (score 1):

TRy this:

```
IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("gu-IN", true);
DateTime dtime = DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text, provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fromdate.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd")
```

change this format it is working

```
fromdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```